# How can I make K8S find Elasticsearch Kind type?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I am following this doc https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/master/k8s-deploy-elasticsearch.html to deploy Elasticsearch on Kuberenete. I have created the spec file:

```yaml
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: quickstart
spec:
  version: 7.15.0
  nodeSets:
  - name: default
    count: 1
    config:
      node.store.allow_mmap: false
```

But I got an error when run `kubectl apply -f es.yml`:

```
 no matches for kind "Elasticsearch" in version "elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1"
```

what should I do to solve the issue? It seems K8S doesn't know this kind `Elasticsearch`. Do I need to install anything?

Comment: Hi, which version of k8s are you using ?

Comment: I believe this thread could help https://discuss.elastic.co/t/unable-to-apply-base-elasticsearch-kubernetes-image/250231

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you may have omitted to install the [custom resource definition (CRD)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/) for elastic.

`Kubectl` version 1.16 and above:

```
kubectl create -f https://download.elastic.co/downloads/eck/1.8.0/crds.yaml
kubectl apply -f https://download.elastic.co/downloads/eck/1.8.0/operator.yaml
```

`Kubectl` version below 1.16:

```
kubectl create -f https://download.elastic.co/downloads/eck/1.8.0/crds-legacy.yaml
kubectl apply -f https://download.elastic.co/downloads/eck/1.8.0/operator-legacy.y
```

Comment: The documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-deploy-eck.html I am glad it fixed your issue!